# При обращении к API через get в Angular 2 ошибка 405

Tags: javascript, http, angular2

Есть некое API требующее авторизации. Я отправляю логин и пароль в headers, но по какой-то причине ошибка 405

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код сервиса:

```
  call(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('demo' + ":" + 'demo'));
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  this._http
    .get('http://api.demo.org', new RequestOptions({headers: headers}))
    .subscribe(data => {
    observer.next(data)
  },
    error => observer.error(error)
  )
})
```

}

И компонента:

```
     this.setUser.call().subscribe(result => {
    console.log( result );
  });
```

Comment: потому что на сервере не разрешен метод Options, который вначале посылает angular

Comment: А как же тогда получить ответ? Через postman все отлично выходит

Comment: @Grundy ангуляр здесь ничего не посылает, это работа браузера, если быть точным

Answer (score 0):

Ты делаешь запрос при помощи JWT, при отправке запроса на сервер происходит следующее:

1. Браузер смотрит на заголовки, заголовок `Authorization`
   автоматически попадает в разряд "сложных", требующих проверку на
   стороне сервера.
2. Браузер автоматически генерирует    запрос(`pre-fligth request`) `options` и отправляет на сервер, чтобы    узнать, какие методы
   разрешены на сервере, здесь начинает работать    `CORS`на стороне
   сервера.

Из вышесказанного можно сделать вывод, что сервер у тебя настроен неправильно, а именно в allowed методах нет `Options`.

Comment: Я пробовал посмотреть API с помощью postman, и всё вышло, как сделать так же в ангулар?

Comment: @Koro6ok это не дело ангуляра, это проблемы на стороне сервера, и что ты надеешься увидеть?

Comment: надеюсь на JSON :) Но если беда на сервере тогда почему вышло получить данные через постман?

Comment: @Koro6ok я не знаю как работает постман, я знаю как работает браузер и сервер с такими запросами, ответ сверху) отталкивайся от него, а не от постмана и получишь Json, а лучше вообще погугли и почитай более подробную инфу про работу браузера, что такое сложные и простые запросы.